# Gradle: How to define sourceControl with sub-path as dependency?

Tags: gradle

Using the sourceControl-Tag I want to use a public repository from google as a dependency within my own project. The repository contains some example java-class which I want to include/use. But since the gradle module/project which providing the neccessary gradle-stuff is located deeper in the file structure of the repository (=> not at root) I struggle on referencing the correct URL. In my settings.gradle I add some lines like that:

```
 sourceControl {
      gitRepository("https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk.git")) {
          producesModule("com.google.ar.core.examples:app")
      }
  }
```

The modules which Im interested in can be fined at
https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk/tree/master/samples/hello_ar_java

Answer (score 4):

Source dependencies is a very cool feature, but is unfortunately rather poorly documented. In cases like this, we have to look at the API documentation. The API for SourceControl is [here](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/vcs/SourceControl.html) (which is the outermost block you use). Here we can see that a `gitRepository` can be configured through [VersionControlRepository](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/vcs/VersionControlRepository.html). And in this, we see that besides the `producesModule` method, there is also a `setRootDir` method with the description:

> void setRootDir​(String rootDir)
>
> Sets the relative path to the root of the build within the repository.

So, based on your repository path, try with this:

```
sourceControl {
    gitRepository("https://github.com/google-ar/arcore-android-sdk.git") {
        producesModule("com.google.ar.core.examples:app")
        rootDir = "samples/hello_ar_java"
    }
}
```